# MAP is a solution to $L(\theta) = \mathcal{I}[\theta \ne \theta^{*}]$

Tags: probability-distributions, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I have come across these slides in one of the online courses. The instructor was trying to explain how Maximum Posterior Estimate(MAP) is actually the solution $L(\theta) = \mathcal{I}[\theta \ne \theta^{*}]$, where $\theta^{*}$ is the true parameter.

Can someone please explain how this follows?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Either the link is broken or it doesn't for those who are not registered to the site you're using.

Comment: Found an answer to this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/349815/167751